# Mysql Search by passing n number of id's

Tags: mysql

i want to get the name of students who is opted for subjects 1,2,3,4 & 5.

```
SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

But i didn't get the expected output. It is not giving me the correct result. Can anyone please help. I am passing this value on to a procedure, so please tell me how to do the search in mysql stored procedure by passing in a list of id's like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `GROUP BY s.name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject) = 5;`

Comment: I guess you didn't read the question before you answer

Comment: do they need to be signed up for all 5 subjects? do they have id's?

Comment: I guess you have stored related subject ids in single column as comma separated values ?

Comment: not i am maintaining as row wise records for each student with their student id.For eg: 1 1 1 - First row of record. 2 1 2- Second Row of record. 3 1 3 third row of record

Comment: It's just not conceivable that you could be storing subjects in a table called students.

Answer (score -1):

Try with quotes around each number:

```
SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject in ('1','2','3','4','5');
```

If the column has value with more than any of these numbers e.g. 1999 or 2777, do it like search:

```
SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject LIKE '1%' 
OR s.subject LIKE '2%'
OR s.subject LIKE '3%'
OR s.subject LIKE '4%'
OR s.subject LIKE '5%';
```

or

```
SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject REGEXP '1|2|3|4|5';
```

Comment: i tried with regexp but i am getting student id's who has not opted for the subjects i pass in. For eg when i pass in 1,2,3 i am getting students id who is not enrolled for subject 3.

Comment: I haven't see your data, please adjust it based on your data in subject column.

Comment: This is wat i tried first SELECT s.id FROM student s WHERE s.subjectId REGEXP ('1|2|3|4|5');

Comment: This is wat i tried second:- SELECT s.id FROM student s WHERE s.subjectId REGEXP ^('1|2|3|4|5');

Comment: How are the IDs are in column, just a single numbers?

Comment: When you use this: SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject='1'; Does it give you the records where id=1 ?

Comment: i was using the query select s.id from students s WHERE s.subjectId IN(1,2,3,4,5); this is how i will be passing i nthe subject id's

Comment: If the data type is not INT, you may have there white-spaces, SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE TRIM(s.subject) in ('1','2','3','4','5');

Comment: When you use this: SELECT s.name FROM student s WHERE s.subject IN(1);  this gives me result perfectly